# Best practice in Django to send request form the template to the database in order to download data

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, database, postgresql

I am working on a Django project where I use Django views in order to get some data from a postgres table and display them in my template view. In the template I also use JQuery to add JS functionality (in dropdown menus etc.).

Right now I pass from my view to the template (through the context_dictionary) the results of a query, where I display in a dropdown menu.

What I want is the user to select one of the values in the dropdown menu and be able to query a postgres table (based on the value he selected) and download the data in a CSV file.

For this purpose I am thinking of using Jquery and Ajax in order to send the query and get back the data. My question is if this is considered an appropriate way to do it or there is a more Django-correct way to send the query.

I am rather new in Django and I am still looking for the best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more about building web apps in general more than it is Django specific. It really comes down to how you want to provide an experience to your user. If you want to go the ajax route, that's fine. If you want to let the user click the submit button and have it load another page, that's fine too.  It just depends on what your end goal is. Sometimes it's easier to take the simple (non-ajax) approach first, and then if you feel a need to use ajax, you can always transition later. Using Django class-based views makes the non-ajax approach really simple.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer certainly shows me an alternative I haven't thought about.